# Rewrite URLs for Specific Language via PHP & htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need some htaccess rules which rewrite URIs like this:

```
http://sub.domain.tld/en/about?a=1&b=2
```

to this:

```
http://sub.domain.tld/about.php?lang=en&a=1&b=2
```

or more simple:

```
http://sub.domain.tld/about.php?a=1&b=2&lang=en
```

No difference...

But the user should see the first URI not the converted one (shouldn't be redirected).

Comment: What have you tried so far? This might be useful: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: @showdev: I'm not familiar enough... I know just a little, so I've no idea about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^/]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule .* %2.php?%3&lang=%1? [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://sub.domain.tld/LangCode/FileName?key1=val1&key2=val2`

With or without trailing slash. Always displayed in browser's address bar,

To:

`http://sub.domain.tld/FileName.php?key1=val1&key2=val2&lang=LangCode`

For permanent redirect, replace `[L]` with `[R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have a index.php which finds client's Location & Language then redirect him to a link like this: http://domain.com/en/ , but in reality PHP should handle this and load the templates with the requested language. so when http://domain.com/en/about is called, PHP will load about page with the English contents. Now my question is: "Does this htaccess rule make any problem?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the .htaccess code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule en/about?a=(.*)&b=(.*)$ about.php?lang=en&a=$1&b=$2
```